# Inserting Related Models with different name of foreign key

Tags: php, laravel-5

I read the document [here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#inserting-related-models) saying eloquent can simplify the process of insert into related model. Usually this will use the table name and append `_id` (eg: `post_id`) at the end. How do i define my own foreign key so that laravel would know which field suppose it to fill?

```
class Post extends Model { 
    protected $primaryKey = 'p_id';
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'co_pid');
    }

}
```

and comment model

```
class Comment extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'co_id';
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'co_pid');
    }   
}
```

and this is my controller's code

```
    $post = Post::firstOrNew([
        'p_title' => $request->input('p_title'),
        'p_content' => $request->input('p_content')
    ]);

$comment = new Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']);

$comment = $post->comments()->save($comment);
```

but this does not work at all and this is the errors came out

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'co_pid' cannot be null
```

Regards and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing I forgot when using `firstOrNew()` is I have to call `save()` method on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter in constraint it's a foreign_key of joined table. So, you have some errors in your code. Try this code:

```
class Post extends Model { 

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'co_id', 'p_id');
    }

}

class Comment extends Model {


    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'p_id', 'co_id');
    }   
}
```